# Connect Oracle with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle9i, oci8

I have php project running on php version 8.1, installed on locale server ubuntu 20.4, in the server there is oracle 9i, Ive instlaled oracle instant client and im trting to connect php project to oracle db, i want to read data from oracle db

ive installed Oracle Instant Client 19.9 as well

```
    $user = "myusername"; 
    $password = "mypassword";
    $ODBCConnection = odbc_connect("Driver={Devart ODBC driver for Oracle};Direct=true;Host=myhost;Port=myport;Service Name=myservicename;User ID=myuserid;password=mypassword", $user, $password);
```

but im getting this error:

Failed to connect to database: ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported.connected

if I have to upgrade the oracle, is there any else workarounds?

Comment: No currently available Oracle client version supports Oracle Server 9i, which is over 25 years old and has been out of support for almost 20. You need to be using a current server version - at least 19c if not 21c or the latest 23c. Note that there is no direct upgrade path from 9i to any currently supported version, and most of the intermediate versions are also no longer available. I'm also curious how you got 9i running on Ubuntu 20, as it would *never* have been certified on that OS.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to connect to a 9i server using a 19c client, or any client newer than 11g. You really shouldn't be doing new development on something so legacy.

But if you have no choice, you can set up a *passthrough* database.

To do so:

1. Choose an available (or install a new) **11.2.0.4** database somewhere (it does not need to be collocated either with your client or the target 9i server).
2. Create a database link in the 11g passthrough to connect to the 9i database.
3. Create views (views provide more functionality than synonyms) over each of the tables you need to work with, pointing to the 9i database through the @databse link. For procedures synonyms will work in most cases.

   E.g.:

   `create view mytable as select * from mytable@my9ilink`

   `create synonym myproc for myproc@my9ilink`
4. Now connect your PHP program with the 19c client to the 11g passthrough database and interact with the views/synonyms that will redirect to the 9i. 11g can talk to both 9i and 19c, so this will work if set up correctly. I don't believe you can do this with 21c; 19c is probably your terminal version to connect to 11g.